# Association table query between different tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have Users, Posts and an association table of Friends to tie the users together.

For a single user, I want to get all Posts that belong to the users who are friends with that user.

```
//user model
function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
function friends() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}

//post model
function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A  bit tricky and messy but should works

```
$friends = $user->friends()->lists('id');
$friendsPosts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $friends);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a `hasManyThrough` relation like:

```
function friendsPosts() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User', 'post_id', 'user_id');
}
```